# Guidelines for migration from Science Fiction & Fantasy

Tags: discussion, migration

I'm putting together [an effort on Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13116/58193) to give users guidance for when they should migrate<sup>1</sup> a question from SFF to a different site on the network.

Arqade has a decent amount of overlap with SFF which means there is potential for a lot of migration of off topic content on SFF to Arqade. SFF generally handles the lore questions whereas Arqade is more about the gameplay aspects of said games.

It would be helpful if the Arqade community could put together some guidance on when they would like content from SFF migrating over here. Things to think about:

- Do you ever want it suggesting?
- What sorts of questions do you want migration suggesting for?
- Are there any topics to avoid?

Once the Arqade community has an idea of what guidelines they have for migration, could you post an answer to the linked post with them? If not let me know in the comments when it is ready and I can post it there.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Here migration means anything from formal migration to suggesting in a comment when to migrate content to a different site.</sub>

Comment: Non-meta-site migration paths rarely exist (only ones I'm aware of are on the big 3 sites), thus migrations can only really be handled by moderators anyway. Is there any benefit to having us write up guidance for SFF mods other than *"Use your best judgement, or ping an Arqade mod in chat if you're unsure"*?

Comment: @Robotnik Well the point is to have a resource to point users to when they suggest something be "migrated" when it really shouldn't be. That way it can help build people's knowledge and minimise future hassle for everyone involved, mostly the OP who gets bounced from Stack to Stack. This isn't necessarily meant to be for formal migration or for just SFF mods.

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer: I am just an experienced user who wants to give their opinion. Some more official guidance from moderators is probably more appropriate.

First, I want to get our ["what topics can I ask about here"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page involved:

> Arqade is for passionate videogamers from all platforms, including
> consoles, computers, handhelds, and mobile devices. If your question
> generally covers things such as …
>
> - Gameplay strategies and tactics
> - Puzzle solving or obstacle clearing
> - Game mechanics and terminology
> - Plot and characters in games
> - Game-specific hardware and utilities
>
> …then you are in the right place to ask your question!
>
> Please note, however, that site policies prohibit questions of the
> following types:
>
> - Game and Mod Development
> - Speculations on future of the industry, upcoming (but unreleased) games or content, and developer intent on mechanics and narrative
> - Requests for game identification based on personal recollection alone.
> - Recommendations for software, hardware, games, or genres.
> - Piracy, and support with pirated games
> - Troubleshooting and diagnosis of modded Minecraft, including crashes, startup errors or other abnormal behaviour caused by modding.

As you can see, we only want questions related to games. We make a minor exception for questions that relate to movies and books derived from games, as long as these questions are related to the games as well.

We generally want to help people enjoy their games. This can be through helping them actually install and run the game (as long as the game isn't modded minecraft), helping with gameplay related questions, helping with narrative conundrums and helping them understand the game systems. Questions to migrate here should be primarily about people needing help with enjoying a game.